# Javascript - How to get particular column's data of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `table`s on my page. I want to pick a particular column from all tables but I am unable to understand the problem with my piece of code.
It looks like this:

```
function getTableColumnValues(){
    var table, columnValue, tableId
    table=document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    for(l=1;l<table.length;l++){
        tableId = table[l].id
        if(tableId != ""){
            columnValue = $(tableId+'>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){ // Here 2 is the column number of which the data I want. 
                $(this).text()
                });
            console.log('TABLE ID: ',tableId);
            console.log("COLUMN VALUE: ",columnValue);
        }
    }
}
```

but my debugger's console shows this:

```
TABLE ID: id_219
COLUMN VALUE: Object[]

TABLE ID: id_220
COLUMN VALUE: Object[]

TABLE ID: id_221
COLUMN VALUE: Object[]
```

Is it ok to place jquery inside javascript code?
Please help me, where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: $("#"+tableId... but why the mix of DOM and jQuery? do $('table').each... and .eq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the `console.log` for the value within the each, as that it the iteration you're looking at:

```
for(l=1;l<table.length;l++){
    tableId = table[l].id
    if(tableId != ""){
        console.log('TABLE ID: ',tableId);
        $(tableId+'>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){ // Here 2 is the column number of which the data I want. 
            var columnValue = $(this).text();
            console.log("COLUMN VALUE: ", columnValue);
        });
    }
}
```

The reason it is currently displaying `Object[]` is because the return value of `each()` is a plain jQuery object - you need to deal with the target element of the iteration within the handler function.

Also, take note of @mplungjan's advice regarding the odd mix of plain javascript and jQuery.

Comment: As seen in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion

1. get only tables with IDs
2. use jQuery .each on the tables and their cells
3. pass the column you want for future flexibility

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/GpcsY/)

```
function getTableColumnValues(col){
    var columnValues=[];
    $('table[id]').each(function() {
        $('tr>td:nth-child('+col+')',$(this)).each(function() {
          columnValues.push($(this).text());
        });
    });
    return columnValues;
}
var vals = getTableColumnValues(2);
window.console && console.log(vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTableColumnValues(){
    var table=document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    for(l=1;l<table.length;l++){
        for(i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
           console.log(table.rows[i].cells[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assumed you need to get the column 2 always.